# How to include the acknowledgement in the built-in table of content?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, page, acknowledgements

Here is my document from the begining:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{ relsize, stackengine}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xurl}



\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % For adding List of Tables and List of Figures to Table of Contents
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
      \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
      \def\@evenfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}}
      \def\@evenhead{\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}% apply new definitions
  

\addbibresource{mybibliography.bib}
%\bibliography{references}
```

Here is the part of my code in which I tried to add the acknowledgement to toc:

```
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}

 \newgeometry{top=1.75in, hmargin=1in ,bottom= 1.3 in} 
 \begin{center}
     ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
 \end{center}
 \vspace{1.5\baselineskip}
 
 
%\hspace{5pt}

\normalsize
\doublespacing
\setlength{\parindent}{.5 in}

\lipsum[1-2]



\vspace*{.5\baselineskip}\noindent\hspace{0.5\textwidth}Jacob A. Ryan
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENT}
\end{document}
```

the problem I faced is that the number of the page for the acknowledgement in the table of content was not correct, the actual page of the acknowledgement was `ii` while in the table of content it was written `iv` which is actually the page numbering of the last page of the table of content, Could anyone help me correct this please?

Comment: Try to move `\addcontentsline` into or before `\begin{center}...\end{center}`. The way you have it now adds the chapter 'ACKNOWLEDGEMENT' after your table of contents, you have to place it where the chapter occurs. I think I read something on this site that there can still be problems, which can be solved by placeing a `\cleardoublepage` before `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you so much!@Οὖτις